# Ошибка No context provided: useLeafletContext() can only be used in a descendant of <MapContainer> при тестировании компонента карты

Tags: reactjs, jest, leafletjs

Пишу тест компонена на jest который рендерит карту и на карте строит маршрут между двумя точками. Использую ReactLeaflet и leaflet routing machine. Код компонента примерно такой:

```
function Component() {
  return (
    <MapContainer>
       center={[project.lat, project.lng]}
        zoom={16}
        maxZoom={18}
      <RoutingMachine />
    </MapContainer>
  );
}
```

Код теста:

```
it('Проверяем что карта в макетах отрисовалась', () => {
  const initialState = {
    mapSearch: {
      zoom: 5,
      dataRoutes: [],
    },
  };

  const store = createStore(reducers, initialState);

  // store.dispatch(replaceMarkersCreator());

  const mapLayout = (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <MapLayout directionsInfo={directionsInfo} mapUpdate={false} />
    </Provider>
  );

  render(mapLayout);

  expect(screen.getByTestId('mapWrapper')).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

При запуске теста получаю ошибку No context provided: useLeafletContext() can only be used in a descendant of .

Естественно во время работы приложения такой ошибки нет. Я новичок в тестах. Есть подозрения, что где то что то не замокано. Но вот где и что не пойму. Прошу накидать идей. Буду искать ошибку методом исключения )). Заранее благодарю.